# Fibonacci sequence using array without using recursion technique

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to generate a code that will display the Fibonacci sequence using an array I did generate a code that has the right solution but I think it's too long since the instructor told us it's gonna be a maximum of 5 lines of code
So here is the method :

```
public static void fibonacci_array_calc(int[] array) {
    int result;
    System.out.println("Fibonacci Series of " + array.length + " numbers: ");
    if (array.length == 0 || array.length == 1) {
        for(int i = 0;i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            result = array[i] = i;
            System.out.print(result + " ");
            if (array[i] >= 1) {
                for (int j = 2; j < array.length; i++, j++) {
                    result = (array[j] = (array[i] + array[i - 1]));
                    System.out.print(result + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output is

```
Fibonacci Series of 10 numbers: 
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

it's not allowed to use the recursion technique is there any way to **shorten** this code?

Comment: You don't need the inner loop. You don't even need the array, actually, just the two previous results.

Comment: No, I need to use the array since it's required, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code by using a conditional assignment to `array[i]`. This assignment can then be used regardless of the length of the input array:

```
public static void fibonacci_array_calc(int[] array) {
    System.out.println("Fibonacci Series of " + array.length + " numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i <= 1 ? i : array[i-2] + array[i-1];
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```